# Concatenate array of dictionaries in one line

Tags: python-3.x

How can I transform the following dictionaries-in-array structure into a dictionary with `'city': 'continent'` structure with just one line?

```
info = [
    ({'Amsterdam':10,'Berlin':20,'London':30},'Europe'),
    ({'Hongkong':10,'Beijng':20,'Manila':30},'Asia'),
    ({'Nairobi':10,'Cape Town':20,'Cairo':30},'Africa')
]
```

This code gives me the answer:

```
a = dict()
for t in info:
    for i in t[0]:
        a[i]=t[1]

{'Amsterdam': 'Europe',
 'Beijng': 'Asia',
 'Berlin': 'Europe',
 'Cairo': 'Africa',
 'Cape Town': 'Africa',
 'Hongkong': 'Asia',
 'London': 'Europe',
 'Manila': 'Asia',
 'Nairobi': 'Africa'}
```

This is incorrect:

```
a = {i:t[1] for i in t[0] for t in info}
```

And another attempt, to concatenate an array of dictionaries, fails as well:

```
a = dict([{i:t[1] for i in t[0]} for t in info])
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3 (see the tag)

Comment: Thanks, but Python 3 point what? The reason I ask is that Python 3.5 added a new way of joining dictionaries (`{**x, **y}`).

Comment: I will accept 3.5 answer as well since I have to update one day anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (tested on 3.5):

```
a = {i: y for x, y in info for i in x}
```